# Wordpress Paid Membership Pro - How to show subscription start date on template?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, membership, subscription

I need some help using the Paid Membership Pro plugin for WP, I would like to show the user in one of our template pages when his subscription started.

Right now I'm using the following code without success

```
<?php $startDate = strtotime(pmpro_getMemberStartdate());
echo "Start date: ".date('l dS \o\f F Y h:i:s A', $startDate); ?>
```

I always get this output:
**Start date: Thursday 01st of January 1970 12:00:00 AM**

that's because it's invalid to transform strtotime that function.

If I use directly pmpro_getMemberStartdate() I get **1423363889**

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution

```
<?php $startDate = date('m-d-Y', pmpro_getMemberStartdate());
echo "Start date: ".$startDate; ?>
```